# Newton Raphson for Cube Root (Precision Error in Double)

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

I am trying to implement Newton Raphson in C++.

Approach: In my `root()` function my `while(temp-e>0)` exists even when `temp==e`. I know it is due to using doubles and comparing double might give precision errors sometimes. But still I want to know how can I make sure that the loop exists only when `temp==0`. Error occurring in the test case `64`. My code is returning `4.000001`, while it should return `4.000000`.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
double root(int n)
{
       double x=n,a,b,e=0.000001,temp;
       a=2*x;
       b=n/(x*x);
       temp=1;
       while(temp-e>0)
       {
                 x=(a+b)/3;
                 a=2*x;
                 b=n/(x*x);
                 temp=(n/(x*x)-x)/3;
                 temp=temp<0?-temp:temp;
       }
       return x;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%lf\n",root(64));
    return 0;
}
```

While this code is giving correct answer, where I am doing two more iterations from where `temp` starts failing:

```
#include<stdio.h>
double root(int n)
{
       double x=n,a,b,e=0.000001,temp;
       a=2*x;
       b=n/(x*x); 
       int i=0;
       temp=1;
       while(i<=2)
       {
                 x=(a+b)/3;
                 a=2*x;
                 b=n/(x*x);
                 temp=(n/(x*x)-x)/3;
                 temp=temp<0?-temp:temp;
                 if(temp<e)
                           i++;
       }
       return x;
}
int main()
{
    int t,n;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
              scanf("%d",&n);
              printf("%lf\n",root(n));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x` may never reach the correct value of `4.0` exactly. Would you prefer an infinite loop over a slightly inaccurate result? The whole point of Newton Raphson is to find an *approximation* that is good enough for your needs.

Comment: 64 is one of the test cases in which it is failing....

Comment: IF if do one more iteration then at which it is exiting, it will give me an accurate result... but i want to know how to deal with this double precision problem.

Comment: @user2379271: It gives you a *more* accurate result, but it's still not exactly 4.

Comment: I am getting exactly <code> 4.000000 </code>

Comment: @user2379271: No you aren't.  Try printing at higher precision.

Comment: @user2379271: if you change the `printf` format to `%.53lf` you'll get a better idea what is going on. You *don't* get exactly `4` with one further iteration, you just get something that's close enough to `4` that it rounds to `4.000000` when printed.

Comment: check out the above program.. It's printing exactly <code>4.000000</code>. I agree that it's giving me more accurate precision but I want exact answer up-to 6 digits till then i want my program to stay in <code>while<code> loop, whenever the program achieves the desired precision. It should exit... That's what i want to do and the problem is <code> double precision</code>

Comment: @user2379271: If you want 6 digits of precision, then change your epsilon appropriately!

Comment: I think epsilon is correct, e=0.000001 . Will you please elaborate what's wrong in it. I want precision upto six digits after decimal point.

Comment: your current code will cycles until the answer is within e, ie within 0.000001  This means your answer, if 4 is correct, will be anywhere between 4.0000010000 and 3.9999990000. If you want more accuracy than this, you must reduce the value of e in the code, or use an alternate termination scheme.

Comment: ok, btw, please dont call cube root functions "root"